# Ignore "404" status pages with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I´m using cURL to get informations out of an API and write them in a MySQL table.

**The url to the API looks like that:**

https://eu.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/item-class/4/item-subclass/1?namespace=static-eu&locale=de_DE&access_token=US6XqgbtQ6rh3EVIqPsejuF62RwP8ljzWn

You can change the number from the url part `1?namespace` to another value, for example to `4?namespace` to get other informations from the API.

I´m using **php "range"** to generate the numbers for the url.

**Problem:**

Some numbers in the url leads to a 404 response, since there are no informations in the API. Example URL:

https://eu.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/item-class/4/item-subclass/18?namespace=static-eu&locale=de_DE&access_token=US6XqgbtQ6rh3EVIqPsejuF62RwP8ljzWn

These "404" pages should get ignored and nothing should be written in MySQL. How is this possible with cURL?

**Complete code:**

```
$ids = [];
foreach(range(0, 20) as $number) {
    $ids[] = $number;
}

$userAgent  =   'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0';
$mh         =   curl_multi_init();
$channels   =   [];

foreach ($ids as $id) {

    $fetchURL = 'https://eu.api.blizzard.com/data/wow/item-class/4/item-subclass/' . $id . '?namespace=static-eu&locale=de_DE&access_token=US6XqgbtQ6rh3EVIqPsejuF62RwP8ljzWn';

    $channels[$id] = curl_init($fetchURL);
    curl_setopt($channels[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($channels[$id], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($channels[$id], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $channels[$id]);
}

// execute all queries simultaneously, and continue when all are complete
$running = null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    curl_multi_select($mh);
} while ($running > 0);

//close the handles
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $channels[$id]);
}

curl_multi_close($mh);

$response   =    [];
foreach($ids as $id){
    $res    = curl_multi_getcontent($channels[$id]);

    $response[$id]  =   ($res === false) ? null : json_decode($res, true);
}

echo ("<pre>");
foreach ($response as $item) {

    $sqle= "REPLACE INTO `itemsubclasses`
                    (`class_id`, `subclass`, `name`)
                VALUES
                    ('{$item['class_id']}', '{$item['subclass_id']}', '{$item['display_name']}')";


    if ($conn->query($sqle) === TRUE) {
        echo "Geklappt";
    } else {
        echo "Problem";
    }
}
```

Comment: After `$response[$id]  =   ($res === false) ? null : json_decode($res, true);` add: `if (isset($response[$id]['code']) && $response[$id]['code'] == '404') $response[$id] = null;`. Obviously you have to check later on if its null in your query loop.

Comment: Perfect, that worked.